# fine tune range`s laziness

Tags: clojure, lazy-evaluation

This code:

```
(first (map (fn [d] 
              (apply * (repeat d 10)))
            (range)))
```

yealds an integer overflow exception, while this code:

```
(first (map (fn [d] 
              (apply * (repeat d 10)))
            (range 0 1)))
```

yealds 1.

Both codes should yeald 1 but for some reason the laziness of range has a strange behaviour. It seems to get chuncks of data instead of only one at a time. Is it possible to make range behave in the desired way?

Comment: Ok, I have just realized that my question is duplicated. But, anyway, I think it should be accepted because it is more straightforward. It is better as a reference than the other one.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`range` is chunked, as a performance optimization. There are a few ways to fix this including using `(iterate inc 0)` or `unchunk` (there are a few versions, this one is copied from [`math.combinatorics`](https://github.com/clojure/math.combinatorics/blob/math.combinatorics-0.0.8/src/main/clojure/clojure/math/combinatorics.clj#L99))

> ```
> (defn unchunk
>   [s]
>   (lazy-seq
>     (when (seq s)
>       (cons (first s)
>             (unchunk (rest s))))))
> ```

```
user=> (first (map (fn [d]
                     (apply * (repeat d 10)))
                   (unchunk (range)))
1
```